# ASP.NET, Trigger codebehind eventhandler with anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, anchor, servercontrols

Is it possible to call an eventhandler codebehind, using an anchor tag? I've tried different things, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried writing my tag like this:

```
<a class="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" runat="server"></a>
```

with no success...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LinkButton for link with server side behaviour.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
  ID="LinkButton1" 
  OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" 
  Text="Link">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" 
     CssClass="Button" Text="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ServerClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.serverclick(v=vs.110).aspx) for handling server side clicks for an anchor tag..